# Auto select in a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Suppose I have a plain html `select` tag. If I click on the select box and start typing the first letter of an item then that item gets auto-selected as I type.

I would like the same functionality for a Bootstrap dropdown menu. Right now, it doesn't respond to any letters that a user types. How can I add the auto-select like the `select` tag has?

Here is an example on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/126297 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to attach a keypress handler when the dropdown is `shown`. Then look through the `li` items to see if the first letter matches the key that was pressed...

```
$('#cars').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    // attach key listener when dropdown is shown
    $(document).keypress(function(e){

      // get the key that was pressed
      var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      // look at all of the items to find a first char match
      $this.find("li").each(function(idx,item){
        $(item).removeClass("active"); // clear previous active item
        if ($(item).text().charAt(0).toLowerCase() == key) {
          // set the item to selected (active)
          $(item).addClass("active");
        }
      });

    });

})
```

Working demo: http://www.bootply.com/126541

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the class `form-control` to the select. I edited your Bootply and while the style of the select does not look correct, the select functions the way you'd like it to. Be sure to follow all of the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) when creating forms.

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that has got me closer but it's not quite what I'm looking for. What I'd like is if the select would keep some text even when the options change. I mean that it would show, for example "important text" no matter what the user clicks on. Is this possible with a select?

Comment: Maybe you want something like [Chosen?](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I have used it personally alongside Bootstrap projects and it works great! Is the first example what you are looking for?

Comment: I've been searching around, and @JustinC you have just saved me! Thank you!