# Select entry from bootstrap dropdown by typing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdownbox

In a bootstrap dropdown, I want to be able to select an entry by typing. E.g. if I have a dropdown with all weekdays and type 'w', I want entry 'Wednesday' to be selected.

From what I found in the [Bootstrap components docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), this isn't out-of-the-box functionality for Bootstrap dropdowns.

I have adapted the Bootply from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772587/auto-select-in-a-bootstrap-dropdown) question to show what I'm trying to achieve:

http://www.bootply.com/lNMmUfyEWM

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This library may be exactly what you want! https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

You can use standard `<select>` and `<option>` tags, but you must initialize it. This would probably be your options:

```
<select id="select-example" placeholder="Select weekday...">
  <option value="">Select weekday...</option>
  <option value="0">Sunday</option>
  <option value="1">Monday</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="4">Thursday</option>
  <option value="5">Friday</option>
  <option value="6">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

and this would be your additional JS (assuming you don't already have a function running on document ready)

```
$(function() {
  return $('#select-example').selectize();
});
```

I've written out an example, and it can be seen here: http://codepen.io/lezed1/pen/cDFLk

A full version (without all the code) can be seen here: http://codepen.io/lezed1/full/cDFLk/